# Domain Root Showing unexpected content

Tags: .htaccess, configuration, hosting

`https://example.com/` this url displaying 'index.php' word as a text on blank page while `https://example.com/index` this url displaying the index content normally.

I developed a web application using php, and hosting from Godaddy (apache server). i config server through `.htaccess`

here is the code:

`

```
RewriteEngine On

# Redirect .php and .html URLs to extensionless URLs
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(.*?/)?(?:index)?(.*?)\.(php|html?)[\s?/] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1%2 [R=301,L,NE]

# Remove .php and .html extensions internally
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.html [L]

# Forbid direct access to the include/ folder
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /include/ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Requested-With} !XMLHttpRequest [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [F,L]

# Allow AJAXHandler.php for XMLHttpRequests
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/include/AjaxHandler\.php$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Requested-With} !XMLHttpRequest [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [F,L]


# Error page redirects
ErrorDocument 404 https://example.com/404
ErrorDocument 500 https://example.com/500
# Redirect to a specific page for forbidden access
ErrorDocument 403 https://example.com/403`
```

All was working fine, when i try to remove 'index' from url, the issue began. But there was no such issue on local server but when i tested on hosting it conflict and now it is not resolving.

I tried to godaddy technical team support, but fail to navigate from where i can start conversation, as their is not such any chat system or any other medium except phone numbers.

Comment: "displaying 'index.php' word as a text on blank page" - What file is rendering that output? That's not _Apache_ behaviour and there's nothing in what you've posted that cause that.